# How to convert SHA1 return value to ascii

Tags: c, sha1, data-conversion

I am trying to create a SHA1 hash of a user input and store it in a string value so I can compare it to a text file of known hashes.

To create the hash:

```
SHA1(password,strlen(password),temp);
print_hex(temp, sizeof(temp));
```

Convert the hash:

```
for(i=0;i<sizeof(passHash);i++){
    sprintf(&passHash[i], "%02x", temp[i]);    
}
printf("%s\n", passHash);
```

Print_hex:

```
void print_hex(unsigned char *buf, int len){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<len;i++){
        printf("%02x",buf[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

When I run the program with a known hashed password like "password" it shows the right hash with print_hex but not after the sprintf. Therefore, I know I am converting the SHA1 hash incorrectly.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what's `passHash`? If it's a pointer, `sizeof(passHash)` probably won't give you what you want.

Comment: You should never, ever be SHA1ing a user password.  Traditional cryptographic hash functions are not intended for passwords.  Instead, you should be using a password based key derivation function like bcrypt, scrypt, pbkdf2, or argon2.  [Here's why](https://www.troyhunt.com/our-password-hashing-has-no-clothes/).

Comment: What do you get?  What do you expect? have you read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are overwriting in your converted string in consecutive `sprintf` calls. Check this:

```
char passHash[100] = {0,};
for(i=0;i<sizeof(temp);i++){
    sprintf(passHash + i * 2, "%02x", temp[i]); // <-- each 2 bytes. e.g: 1 = 01, 255 = FF
}
printf("%s\n", passHash);
```

Each byte takes 2 character in hex string, so you need to increase `sprintf` target buffer by 2. In addition, `temp` is the buffer that you are reading from, so your `for` loops should loops for `sizeof(temp)`, not `sizeof(passHash)`.

By the way, this is a sample code that shows your bug and I don't say this is best code.